# fsolve for function with exp

Tags: numpy, math, scipy

I'm trying to solve a nonlinear equation with Python and Scipy, heres the simple input:

```
from numpy import exp
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def func(x):
    return 5*x*(2*x-1+exp(2*x))-5


x0 = fsolve(func,0)

print(x0)
```

However executing the function leads to `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp` message. 
Using Matlab and fzero with the same function works fine and returns 0.4385 for the root.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

using 0 as a starting estimate causes some problems
you can use any arbitary value and if you want to start from zero use something like 1e-6

```
from numpy import exp
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def func(x):
    return 5*x*(2*x-1+exp(2*x))-5


x0 = fsolve(func,1e-6)

print(x0)
```

yields

```
[0.43848533]
```